# How to testing with Add-ons Rested Client

Tags: javascript, html, rest, add-on

anyone know how to write this in RESTED Add ons mozilla

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var form = new FormData();
form.append("cluster", "pejaten");
form.append("content", "Jokowi");
form.append("flag", "");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://10.100.17.245:8081/manager/services/client/processString",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/xml"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
</script>
```

and success with that..

but, i trying with rested add-ons in mozile show error 400..
please correct me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dmFp.png)

Error Header SHOW :

```html
Date: Thu, 22 Feb 2018 08:40:45 GMT
Cache-Control: must-revalidate,no-cache,no-store
Content-Type: text/html;charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Length: 354
Server: Jetty(9.3.z-SNAPSHOT)
```

ERROR REVIEW SHOW :

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 400 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 400</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /manager/services/client/processString. Reason:
<pre>    Bad Request</pre></p>
<hr /><a href="http://eclipse.org/jetty">Powered by Jetty:// 9.3.z-SNAPSHOT</a><hr/>
</body>
</html>
```